# ASP.NET MVC: CSS file returning a 302 error when it exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, http-status-code-302

I'm getting a 302 error returning on a single CSS file on an ASP.NET MVC 2 site in localhost this morning and I don't know what would have changed to cause this.

The localhost site uses IIS 7.5, though I've had limited experience with IIS so I haven't looked to much in to what could be going on there.

The URL to the CSS file is:

```
http://localhost/MySite/Content/Site.css?v=16
```

and the location header on the response looks like this:

```
/MySite/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%MySite%2fContent%2fSite.css%3fv%3d16&v=16
```

This makes me think that MVC is redirecting the static file or something like that, however if that was the case, then I would expect all my images, CSS and JavaScript files to be doing the same which they're not. Just in case, here is a simplified version of `RegisterRoutes()` in Global.ascx:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("", "Account/{action}/", new { controller = "Account" });
    routes.MapRoute("", "{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults               
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Error",
        "{*url}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "ResourceNotFound" }
    );
}
```

Also, if I change the name of my CSS file to Site2.css and reference that instead, the same thing happens.

What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The redirect to the logon method makes it look like this is because of permissions on the directory or the file rather than an MVC route catching it. (If it were caught by an MVC route, it would probably rather result in an error determining which controller and/or action to use.)

ASP.NET MVC itself leaves static files alone, but if ASP.NET in general decides that the anonymous user doesn't have access to the CSS file or its directory, ASP.NET will redirect to the log-on URL, which will be an ASP.NET MVC action.

Comment: Ahh that's it. It was a permissions issue on that specific CSS file rather than the entire content directory (which would have made the same thing happen for all static content). Still not sure how those permissions were changed however. Giving rights to the account that the AppPool was using for authorization fixed the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was permissions on the file itself and not just the directory.

Comment: I already checked, this answer made me check again.. mine wasn't just on the file but it made me review the permissions for a 5th time as it confirmed what I had thought.. in my case my compared environment slapped "Users" group on the sites folder. Wouldn't say that is a best practice it just happened to be the group the environment was missing. Using IUSR directly worked of course but I kept them matching to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the authorization rules in the web.config are saying that you have to be authenticated to see the css pages. You should be able to prove that by logging in and seeing if you can get the css file to be served correctly.

I'd add a location section to the web.config to remove the authorization requirement on the content directory. Taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871

```
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to all of the files that are stored in the Content folder.  -->
<location path="content">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```